# How to autoload a user-defined class in CI4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'd like to get a user-defined constants file out of the native `\Config\Constants.php` from CI4

I would like to write a class like :

```
public class UserConstants{
    const YEAR = 2024;
    const MAX = 9999;
    const FOO = "myfoo";
}
```

or

```
class UserConstantsStaticWay
{
    private static $year;
    private static $max;
    private static $foo;

    public static function getYear():int {return self::$year;}
    public static function getMax():int {return self::$max;}
    public static function getFoo():string {return self::$foo;}
}
```

This would allow me to use syntax such as `UserConstants::YEAR` or `UserConstantsStaticWay::getYear()` in my Controllers or even in my Views.

In CI4, where could I define such a class?
What would be the most elegant way? in `Config`, `Service`, `Library`, a simple class definition or other?

And more importantly, **how could I load it automatically and make it available in all Controllers and Views**? Then not only in the `BaseController` definition.

I'm not talking about `CI4's Autoload PSR4` namespaces here, but rather the old `Resources CI3 Autoloader`.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/Autoloader/Autoloader.php

Comment: Why not have the constants in your User model? Secondly, what's the use case of these constants?

Comment: @shirshak007: no, this is the classic PSR4-namespaces autoloader.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa: These constants store technical codes, often representing strings that I want to pass as arguments, or dispose in my queries, filters, helpers, RFC dates formats, etc. So I can use them in the front layer, back layer, DB calls, JS, etc. I use enumerations for a similar purpose too. But I'd like to externalise all of these from `Constants.php`, which I think is more CI-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a [Global Constant](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html#global-constants) in `app/Config/Constants.php`

```php
class UserConstants{
    const YEAR = 2024;
    const MAX = 9999;
    const FOO = "myfoo";
}

define("UserConstants", UserConstants::class);
```

Usage anywhere within your application

```php
echo (new (UserConstants))::FOO;
```

Comment: Thank you, interesting. I think I'll reuse the principle (but using `const` and an `abstract` class) to find a solution. I'll post a reply.

Comment: Actually, if you just create the `class UserConstants`inside `Config\Constants.php` file, you can call `UserConstants::YEAR`from anywhere. It's a quite pretty solution (despite it's remaining in the same Constants.php file). No need  then to `define("UserConstants", UserConstants::class);`I'm still just wondering if I will go for a classic `class` or an `abstract class`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer of @steven7mwesigwa, I suggest this way, despite it's still inside Constants.php:

in **Config\Constants.php**

```
abstract class UserConstants
{
    const YEAR = 2024;
    const MAX = 9999;
    const FOO = "myfoo";
}
```

Then you can use `UserConstants::YEAR` from anywhere (controllers & views).

Comment: With this approach, in my case, you don't get "navigate to source" functionality in the IDE (phpstorm). Additionally, as much as it works,  my IDE warns that the class hasn't been imported.

Comment: Very strange, my PHPStorm handles it perfectly. @steven7mwesigwa

Comment: My bad. I had to add a backslash to indicate that it was from the default namespace. `\UserConstants::FOO`